# How to compile Youtube WatchMe?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, youtube-api, apk, live-streaming

I am trying to (roughly) replicate the Sony Xperia "Live on Youtube" app. Since it is exclusive to the Xperia line, I am trying to build an app out of the [Youtube WatchMe source code](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme).

All I need is an app that can live stream video from the phone's camera to Youtube, as both of the apps mentioned above do. I know that WatchMe is meant to be nothing more than a reference for developers wanting to make apps that utilize this, but how possible would it be to modify the example code? I don't need a necessarily *stable* application, but something is better than nothing.

It would help even more if anyone knew of an app that already contained this functionality.

Comment: Very few people have been able to compile this project properly.  Google has provided very little information on what version of ffmpeg to use, how they configured the NDK-level component, and other vital information.  I'm in the same boat currently.  I would recommend you check the GitHub issues page and see what other developers have figured out: https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to sharing and open-source limitations of ffmpeg I wasn't able to distribute the built.

There were few people built successfully [in here](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/issues/16). They use ffmpeg + libx264 v2.3.

You'll also use [Android.mk and ffmpeg-jni.c](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/tree/master/app/src/main/jni) from the repo to build.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TubeStreamer, now on Google Play. This is a work in progress but is currently working for streaming live video to YouTube.

Comment: The original post said this "It would help even more if anyone knew of an app that already contained this functionality." Sorry if my answer didn't help with what the original poster was wanting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to make this app worked.
I made it run on my phone, but with the wrong build method.
Here's my progress, just for reference.

I compiled the app on Eclipse except the libffmpeg.so.
Then, I got the lib file from someone provided on https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/issues/16
Finally, I push the file into the phone's directory "/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.watchme-1/libffmpeg.so"

After these steps and configure on Google develope console and Youtube, this app could run correctly.